# R ggplot modifying the legend to have custom elements

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(RColorBrewer)


colours <-brewer.pal(n = 3, name = 'Paired')

ids <- c("TestA", "TestB", "TestC")
bg <-c(23, 13, 15)
s1 <- c(21,15,17)
s2 <- c(27,25,11)
s3 <- c(24,14,18)
df <- data.frame(ids, bg, s1,s2,s3)
colors <- c("bgs"= "grey", "tid1"=colours[1], "tid2"=colours[2], "tid3"=colours[3])


ggplot(df, aes(x = ids)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = bg, color = 'bgs'), fill = 'grey', size = 1, ) +
  geom_point(aes(y = s1, color= 'tid1'), size = 10, group = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = s2, color= 'tid2'), size = 10, group = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = s3, color='tid3'), size = 10, group = 1)+ 
  labs(x = "Year",
       y = "(%)",
       color = "Legend") +
  scale_color_manual(values = colors)+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

This code produces the following graph:
[image]

The issue here is with the legend, i have used the fill = 'grey' in order to fill the bar chart in geom_col(). However you can see that this now produces a grey box over which the other elements in the legend are placed. Is there a way to show just the gray box for the bg data, and show colored circles only for the other data in the legend

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think you just want to remove the graph box in the legend that shows nothing?  I'd ask in a comment but I don't have enough reputation yet :(

This is happening because you are specifying `color =` inside the `aes()` argument.  The easiest way to get rid of this is to get rid of `color = bgs`.

Since you are working with a barchart, what `color =` does is add a 'border' of specified color around your graph.  Whereas `fill =` is the color that actually fills in the color of the bars.  So here is what the code and the graph would look like:

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3
library(RColorBrewer)


colours <-brewer.pal(n = 3, name = 'Paired')

ids <- c("TestA", "TestB", "TestC")
bg <-c(23, 13, 15)
s1 <- c(21,15,17)
s2 <- c(27,25,11)
s3 <- c(24,14,18)
df <- data.frame(ids, bg, s1,s2,s3)
colors <- c("bgs"= "grey", "tid1"=colours[1], "tid2"=colours[2], "tid3"=colours[3])


ggplot(df, aes(x = ids)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = bg), fill = 'grey', size = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = s1, color = 'tid1'), size = 10, group = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = s2, color = 'tid2'), size = 10, group = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = s3, color = 'tid3'), size = 10, group = 1)+ 
  labs(x = "Year",
       y = "(%)",
       color = "Legend") +
  scale_color_manual(values = colors)+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

There are other ways to do this too, including `override.aes()` (I think).  If you are curious take a look at Hadley Wickham's book on ggplot2.  There is a free pdf here: [ggplot2 book](http://www.ievbras.ru/ecostat/Kiril/R/Biblio_N/R_Eng/Wickham2016.pdf)

I think you would want to look at chapter 6 which covers the legends